# How to remove "height" setting for images in CKEditor 4

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I need to remove "Height" setting for images in CKEditor 4.
I mean that users will be allowed ONLY to enter "Width". Simple hiding "Height" in HTML is not enough as CK Editor 4 will add height in CSS anyway. I need it to stop adding height at all and hide this option. "Lock proportions" icon should be gone and "Restore size" icon should be working but setting only width as well.
How can I do this? Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    disableObjectResizing : true
});
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    var  editorO = ev.data.definition.dialog.getParentEditor();

    if ( dialogName == 'image' || dialogName == 'image2' ) {
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );

        if( dialogName == 'image' ){
            infoTab.remove('txtHeight');
            infoTab.remove('ratioLock');
        }
        else{
            infoTab.remove('height');
            infoTab.remove('lock');
        }
    }
});
```

You need to look for `id's` in dialog files:

- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js#L694
- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/image2/dialogs/image2.js#L478

Comment: Wow, this worked! Thanks. Now, how do I get rid of the "lock proportions" lock icon ?

Comment: Thanks. Your updated code works, even though it also removed the "restore size" icon which would be nice to have. Can you also explain how did you figure out these IDs ?

Comment: I have added https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#disableObjectResizing to editor configuration because I have noticed that Firefox native image resize feature adds width/height to images. Just in case I would recommend filtering the HTML for images on the server side and removing any height you find in styles or attributes (if your goes is to not have the height at all).  As for ID’s – I have been working with CKEditor for a while now so I know a thing or two ;)

Comment: For the image2 plusgin, removing the "height " would make the 'width' field disabled. How can I solve it?